# Affiliate API of AliExpress (Taobao) - get products info

Tags: product, group, affiliate, aliexpress

Maybe you can help me.
I am using the Affiliate API of AliExpress (Taobao) to get list of products by search key. It looks like this:
https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=45803&docType=2&fbclid=IwAR223r-KlDbNtvmufFUbh344ODuGFHHlZiNGmqqzcoP9-q5vq2AaYfds95A

```
AliexpressAffiliateProductQueryResponse rsp = runAliExpressRequest(requestSiteReport);
ArrayList<AliexpressAffiliateProductQueryResponse.Product> itemsList = rsp.getRespResult().getResult().getProducts();
```

Sometimes their are product that includes inside them other products (like a group).
My question is: how can I know if a product is single or a group and how can I get all the products inside the group?

I tried the end point
"https://api-sg.aliexpress.com/sync"
with the param:
method=aliexpress.affiliate.product.query
And I get the products, but i expected that in each product will be param that called products_sons that will include all the product inside the product father or empty if the father product is a single product.